# How small does a hole in a cup have to be to hold water without dripping?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, water

I am creating a drain that lets water in but keeps pieces of plastic out. I need to know the size of a standard water droplet.

Comment: This question seems to be more about [DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) than physics. Also, what is a standard water droplet?

Comment: Why not work with the size of the plastic pieces?

Comment: You're describing simple filtration - and the relations between pore size, particle size and the pressure gradient are not so straightforward. Can you give us some more details?